# DECODE Function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert the following query and I get syntax errors. Can you please help me with the below query:

```
INSERT INTO ABCTABLE (COLUMN1) values ('DECODE(MDSE_CD,NULL,'0000000000000000',LPAD(TO_NUMBER(MDSE_CD,'16',' '))');
```

Comment: I think we really need to know what are you trying to achieve with that statement. Syntax errors can be fixed. But what are you trying to do: inserting a new row, updating existing rows in the table, assigning a literal string to COLUMN1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try properly escaping the inner single quotes

```
INSERT INTO ABCTABLE (COLUMN1) 
VALUES ('**DECODE**(MDSE_CD,NULL,''0000000000000000'',**LPAD**(TO_NUMBER(MDSE_CD,''16'','' ''))');
```

Comment: Thanks it worked,But when it is NULL do i need to give ''0'' OR ''0000000000000000'' to fill the column with 000000000000

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't really said anything other than "this query doesn't work, fix it", I have to take a stab in the dark what you want. From the query you have, I'm therefore guessing you want the value of the column to be `DECODE(MDSE_CD,NULL,'0000000000000000',LPAD(TO_NUMBER(MDSE_CD,'16',' '))`

In which case, you have to escape the single quotes within your string literal. Do this by doubling up the quotes:

```
INSERT INTO ABCTABLE (COLUMN1) 
VALUES ('DECODE(MDSE_CD,NULL,''0000000000000000'',LPAD(TO_NUMBER(MDSE_CD,''16'','' ''))')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the use of quote marks. If we tried to break up your query it would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO ABCTABLE
  (COLUMN1) 
values 
  (
    'DECODE(MDSE_CD,NULL,'
    0000000000000000
    ',LPAD(TO_NUMBER(MDSE_CD,'
    16
    ','
    '))'
  );
```

...which clearly makes no sense.

You might want to think about how to escape a quote mark inside a string.

Answer (score 1):

Sql Server:

DECOD function in Sql Server can be replaced with CASE construct

LPAD function in Sql Server has not a direct correspondence but you can pad your string using string manage function REPLACE (replicate a character a number of specified times)

My Sql:

DECOD function in MySql can be replaced with CASE construct

LPAD function in MySql is existent

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to store... a string literal `'DECODE(MDSE...))'`, or did you want to call a function to derive a value?

To store a string literal containing single quotes, you need to "escape" each single quote within the string with an extra single quote, e.g.

```
O'Hare Int'l   ==>  'O''Hare Int''l'
```

The `DECODE` function is Oracle specific. That expression will need to be rewritten using different functions in both MySQL and SQL Server.